# z wave and zigbee development boards

Tags: esp8266, zigbee, zwave

`ESP8266` provides an amazing environment to build iot devices for smart home. I managed to build all kinds of gadgets raging from simple temperature and humidity recorders to more advanced actors with sensor motions and appliance controls. There are [tons of components](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000095377908.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.56a15c15F0a6gv&algo_pvid=b201eb38-dcee-4972-92dd-84b505895bb8&algo_expid=b201eb38-dcee-4972-92dd-84b505895bb8-11&btsid=8a186a12-5943-42be-ac91-f5d535b37f80&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_10,searchweb201603_60) for those available.

Recently, I entered into the area of automation of heating in smart house, discovered the `homematic ip` a line of products and got impressed how energy efficient and what an impressive operating range they have.

My current setups involve many nodemcu's (as well as off-the-shelf homematic and zigbee devices) on one side and raspberry pi 3 with openhab integrating those into one thingy on the other side.

I got these questions:

1. I wonder how steep is the learning curve to get into the zigbee/zwave development.
2. Thanks to nodemcu, one could start developing and testing the setups within days. Is there any similar inexpensive development boards are there? I tried to browse the net a bit, but all I got were kits costing at least a few hundred euro/dollar.
3. Can one reuse the same sensor components to work with zigbee/z wave boards?

Comment: URL for [Homeatic IP](https://www.homematic-ip.com/en/smart-home.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have done anything on the ESP8266 with MQTT, and are interested in controlling devices at home, you might want to look at [zigbee2mqtt](https://www.zigbee2mqtt.io).  Development is pretty active on that project.

I've been using all Digi zigbee hardware for the most part, but you can probably get started with a CC2531 USB stick flashed with the zigbee coordinator firmware, and a single XBee zigbee RF module that communicates with your MCU of choice over the TX/RX connection.  Breadboard breakouts and FTDI interfaces are readily available for the Digi modules as well.

Comment: thanks for sharing your ideas. I have some experience with MQTT, and would love to try out zigbee2mqtt. I have a CC2531 usb stick from https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B07V9K3GHH/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o04_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1 and managered to connect it to openhab. Which device would you suggest for xbee zigbee RF on aliexpress?

Comment: I've only used Digi XBee RF modules myself, but any of the CC2530 modules with zigbee _should_ work.  From aliexpress you can try versions with the [external antenna](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33007098493.html) or [PCB antenna](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1861120386.html).

Answer (score 1):

Some additional resources on the net how to connect arduino&co with xbee.

ForceTronics blog:

- Part 1: http://forcetronic.blogspot.com/2014/01/building-wireless-temperature-sensor.html
- Part 2: http://forcetronic.blogspot.com/2014/01/building-wireless-temperature-sensor_9.html